# pybind11 export C++ function (no arguments) to python module constant attributes/variables?

Tags: python, c++, constants, pybind11

Is it available to bind **C++ non-arguments function** to **Python constant attributes/variables in module** ?

For example, I have such code:

```
int my_constant() { return 0; }

PYBIND11_MODULE(constants, m) {
  m.attr("MY_CONSTANT") = py::int_([](){ return my_constant(); });
}
```

And I hope I could use it in python3 console:

```py
>>> from constants import MY_CONSTANT
>>> MY_CONSTANT
0
```

Is it available to do that ?

Comment: `m.attr("MY_CONSTANT") = my_constant();`?

Comment: @super, can't be, this will call `my_constant` function when loading `constants` module, I want `my_constant` been called every time it been used.

Comment: Then just expose the function itself? What exactly is the question?